# Need to force a "div" every "nth" record from an array

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

In creating a set of records to help us print registration badges I'm attempting to force the page displays to insert a page-break div every 6th. record. I'm sure there are numerous ways to do this and hoping to get there quickly if possible.

```
    </th...>
%%[ Var @rows, @row, @GUID, @Name, @Event, @Preference
SET @TableRows = LookupOrderedRows("Registrations" , 0, "RegisterDate Desc", "eventGUID", @eventGUID)
SET @TableRowCount = RowCount(@TableRows)
FOR @i = 1 to RowCount(@TableRows) do
SET @TableRow = Row(@TableRows, @i)
SET @GUID = Field(@TableRow, "RegID")
SET @Name = Field(@TableRow, "RegName")
SET @Company = Field(@TableRow, "RegCoName")
<tr class="labelBlock">
--- Add table rows and inserts fields - this part works but... ---
%%[ NEXT @i ]%%
```

So we're using that premise to create a table, but every 6th. record needs to be a  tag primarily to create the required page breaks. My thought process leans towards a record count and every whole number multiple of 6 is followed by that  Not sure how I'll do that but seeking other suggestions or methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just looking for the AMPscript to do the multiple of six? The MOD operator should work.

```
%%[IF MOD(@i, 6) == 0 THEN ]%%

---Page break code

%%[ENDIF]%%
```

I don't have anything more elegant off the top of my head.

Comment: Maybe this could be shown in context of Johnnys code,  so he knows where to put it.

Comment: Believe I can determine that but will bring back to share once it is working. If I'm unable I'll come back to (humbly) ask. d(-o-)

Comment: To follow through I placed this at the end of the table row and TD preceding the %%[ NEXT @i ]%%, lo and behold! (magic) and I can see the div with the class = "pagebreak" every 6th. record as desired.